# Expose a server on port 80 via kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm attempting to expose a server on port 80 via kubernetes.

Start minikube :

```
minikube start
```

Create a deployment by running the command

```
"kubectl create deployment apache --image=httpd:2.4"
```

Create a service by running the command

```
"kubectl create service nodeport apache --tcp=80:80"


kubectl get svc
```

returns :

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
apache       NodePort    10.105.48.77   <none>        80:31619/TCP   5s
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        43s
```

I've attempted to open 10.105.48.77 & 10.96.0.1 on port 80 but the service is not running.

How to start a simple http server on port 80 via kubernetes that will serve requests to that same port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NodePort` has a range `30000-32767`. Your log shows `31619` is assigned, you may try that. If you really want port 80 you will need other types of service, for example `LoadBalancer`. You can also use `port-forward` to forward you local port `80` to the `apache` pod.

Comment: thanks but both cluster IP 10.105.48.77:31619 & localhost:31619 are both inaccessible.

Comment: is the pod running? what do you see when you run `kubectl get pod`